# Invalid acces token - Graph Api with R

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Until a month ago I was using the Rfacebook library with no problems. When I load the token I had generated and I want to use some function for example

```
getUsers("me",fb_oauth) #fb_oauth is my token
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) : 
  Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 04-Apr-17 13:24:59 PDT. The current time is Tuesday, 02-May-17 06:33:21 PDT.
```

To try to solve it I generate a new password in the app and generate a new token and I get the new token correctly:

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="12345678", app_secret="xxxx")

Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: http://localhost:1410/ 
When done, press any key to continue...
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
```

But when I want to use the same function it gives me error

```
Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) : 
  An access token is required to request this resource.
```

[Also configure the login in the app but it does not work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1WVW.jpg)
Anyone know how to generate the new token with the new 2.9 update?

Regards

Comment: The access token return format has changed between API v2.2 and v2.3, and v2.2 was shut down end of March - so it likely has to do with that. First of all, make sure you are up-to-date regarding the packages you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I currently have all packages installed and updated but the error continues

Comment: Are you specifying the API version to use anywhere with that package?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and have not been able to find a solution. I even posted an issue to the GitHub of the creator of RFacebook but have not received a response yet

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I still have the error. Someone could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe mentioned, the access token return format has changed and therefore the problem seems to be, that the credentials (including the access token) returned when authorizing with facebook is saved as the field name/key instead of the field value.

So a fix to this would be the following:

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id, app_secret, extended_permissions = FALSE,legacy_permissions = FALSE) 

fb_oauth_credentials <- fromJSON(names(fb_oauth$credentials))
```

and then to make a request, such as getting a page would be;

```
fb_page <- getPage(page = "FBUserNameHere",
                   token = fb_oauth_credentials$access_token)
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh You're right, this worked perfectly. And thanks CBroe too!